# array inside a function

Tags: c++, arrays, function

I want to create an array inside a function just like this:

```
int function(int a){
    int something[a]{};
    return something;
}
```

but the next error "expression must have a constant value" appear.

Comment: `int something[a]{};` What did you intend this line to do? Simply create an `array` of size `a`?

Comment: C++ does not support VLA, use `std::vector` instead

Comment: Arrays must have a constant size. "a" is not a constant. Open your C++ book to the chapter that explains how to use a `std::vector`, and read it.

Comment: Do you need this?
    
    `int* function(int a){
          int* something = new int[a];
          return something;
     }`

Comment: Forget about all of this and use `std::vector`. However, what you really want to do here remains a bit of a mystery, because your `return` statement makes no sense.

Comment: Stuff like `int something[a]{};` isn't valid C++, because [C++ doesn't have variable length arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1887097/9254539). You should use an `std::vector` instead.

Answer (score -1):

Your code doesn't really make sense, you are trying to create an array `something`, and then return an array from a function that is supposed to return an `int`. ***Guessing at your intentions***,

If you want to return an `int` from an array based on index `a`, you could:

`test.cpp`

```
#include <iostream>

int function(int a){
    int something[] = {1,2,3};
    return something[a];
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << function(1) << std::endl;
}
```

Compile using `$ g++ test.cpp -o test`
Run using `$ ./test`